# Does Google Maps provide Search By Catogory?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm new to Google Maps and Android and I want to know if google provides searching by categories. For example, if someone wants to pay bills, can Google provide him or her a direction like this bank is near to you so please pay your bill.

I actually want to know how Google knows that this is bank or this is something else, is it by longitude, latitude or some other criteria?

I simply want match coordinates of the user and notify him when something is close to him (assuming that he is in need to pay bills, buy medicines or so).